# How to apply custom validation on MutualExclusiveFields (email or mobile) for Spring Controller @RequestParam?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-validator

I have a Spring Boot get API with @RequestParam, I need help in applying custom validation on MutualExclusiveFields (email or mobile). i.e I would like to make sure that "email" or "mobile number" is not null ? any one Should be available.

```
public ResponseEntity<Response> employeeInfo(@ApiParam(value = "empiId",required = true, example = "1")
    @RequestParam(name ="empiId",required = true) Long empiId,
    @RequestParam(name ="emailId",required = false) String emailId,
    @RequestParam(name ="mobileNumber",required = false) String mobileNumber) {

        System.out.println(empiId+ emailId+mobileNumber); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```
public ResponseEntity<Response> employeeInfo(@ApiParam(value = "empiId",required = true, example = "1")
    @EmployeeId @RequestParam(name ="empiId",required = true) Long serviceRequestId,
    @EmailId @RequestParam(name ="emailId",required = false) String emailId,
    @Mobile @RequestParam(name ="mobileNumber",required = false) String mobileNumber) {

        System.out.println(empiId+ emailId+mobileNumber); 
}
```

**Custom Phone Validator Inteface**

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PhoneValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Phone{

    String message() default "Wrong!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**Custom Phone Validator Implemenation**

```
@Component
public class PhoneValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Phone, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Phoneparam) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String givenParam, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return givenParam!= null && givenParam.matches("[0-9]+")
          && (givenParam.length() > 8) && (givenParam.length() < 14);
    }

}
```

**To Use Spring Validation Implementation Need to define below @Bean  at Configuration Class**

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
    return methodValidationPostProcessor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm looking for MutualExclusiveFields i.e emailId and Mobile. In details. request should have any one of the values, emailId or Mobile , empid is always mandatory.

Comment: But you have required true which always looks for value

Comment: @RequestParam(name ="emailId",required = false) String emailId,
 @RequestParam(name ="mobileNumber",required = false) String mobileNumber) here emailId and mobileNumber "required = false". We can do mutual exclusive fields on model Object but I wonder is it even possible for RequestParams. If so what would be the best way to do this.